# Raspberry Pi Secure Boot Configurations with Authentication IC

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, bootloader, u-boot

I am working on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 with raspbian buster (command line only) os.
I want to secure my Raspberry Pi, I have read some solutions on that.

As I see there some manufacturers providing the Authentication IC to store the Keys & secure the boot. But I don't know How to use them with Raspberry Pi.

I want to secure Raspberry Pi at its boot level with an external Authentication IC interface with an integrated secure key. After powered-up, the Raspberry Pi must read the security key. if it's found and matched then n then only pi get booted.

Is that possible? If yes, How?

Comment: is that possible? You say "As I see there some solutions using the Authentication IC to store the Keys & secure the boot.", so, I guess it must be possible if you've found solutions. as to How? well, didn't you say you've found solutions?

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes I have found solutions. i.e. There some IC's used for authentication purposes to secure the hardware. But I am not found any dedicated solution with the raspberry pi 4/CM4 modules.

Comment: Oh, your question implies you searched and found for Pi Compute Module secure boot

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited the question now, do you have any idea how to secure booting of raspberry pi using Authentication IC's.